# Google Maps API v3 Rank by Distance Unexpected Results

Tags: google-maps, maps

I ran into an issue with the rank by distance search from the Google API here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests
I receive several results when using a radius search of 50km, but if I do a rank by distance search I only receive a few.

Example Requests:

## Radius Request

```
var request = {
    location: whatever,
    radius: '50000',
    types: ['grocery_or_supermarket']
};
```

## Rank by Request

```
var request = {
    location: whatever,
    rankby : google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    types: ['grocery_or_supermarket']
};
```

EDIT:

I am using the nearbySearch. I understand there is a cap of 20 on the nearbySearch, but the rankby search is only returning 1-5 results when using the rankBy flag. The radius search returns the maximum of 20.

Comment: Did you find your answer? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not difference between radar search and rank by distance but between radar search and nearbySearch.

Google docs for radar search:

*A Radar Search lets you search for Places within a specified search radius by keyword, type or name. The Radar Search **will return more results** than a Nearby Search or Text Search, but the results **will contain less detail** - only the Place reference and a LatLng object. You can get more information about any of the Places in the response with the PlacesService.getDetails() method.*

So using [example from Google site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) with `nearbySearch` there are 20 results, with `radarSearch` there are 80 results.

In both cases I used the following request (with or withoud `rankby`):

```
  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    rankby : google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,
    types: ['store']
  };
```

Comment: What does it have to do with his question?